# How can I achieve this task in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and trying to achieve this task by the `Row()` widget but am not able to complete it.

[image: Please check screenshot]

Comment: Questions that are vague and broad, and consist mostly of an image are not appropriate here. Please [edit] your post to clearly describe the problem you're having, include your efforts to solve the problem yourself, and ask a **specific question**. I'd suggest you review [ask] to get some tips on how to post a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `row` and `Expanded` around the `Divider`s to avoid overflowing.

```
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: Divider()),
        Text('Some Text'),
        Expanded(child: Divider()),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using a `Stack` widget. The `Stack` widget basically places all its `children` over each other.
The code can look something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Divider(),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Text('or sign in with'),
    ),
  ],
);
```